# NiFi PutS3Object Error - Connection TimeOut

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi

I am trying to add a file to S3 bucket using NiFi. I have configured IAM role for authentication. Getting the error PutS3Object Failed to put StandardFlowFileRecord to Amazon S3 due to Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to sts.amazonaws.com:443  failed: connect timed out com.amazonaws.SdkClientException.
My NiFi instance is installed on ec2 instance and from that ec2 instance I am able to transfer file to S3 bucket using aws cli.

Comment: This is common, you will have to create a retry loop for all failed flow due to timeout.

Is this happening to all flows ?

Comment: Yes this is happening for all flows. I am able to transfer files to S3 bucket from ec2 instance where NiFi is installed. This error happens in NiFi processor only. Do we have to do some configuration at Nifi application level for connecting to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your STS service, the "*client*" - nifi processor module uses and endpoint via public internet unless you have setup an [VPC Endpoint for STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_sts_vpce.html)

Comment: As part of troubleshooting we have created one IAM user and configured access key and secret key in NiFi PutS3Object processor. Then we were able to successfully transfer the file to S3 Bucket. The issue comes in only when using the IAM role .Do we have to add any configuration to the IAM role specific to NiFi Application?

Answer (score 0):

@Tris

Assuming you have everything allowed and configured at firewall, access, and SSL Context Service, the timeout should be able to be resolved by increasing the timeout values in the processor.  Sometimes the default settings are not sufficient.